# Replace that kind of list in a dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list, replace

I have a column named categories in a dataframe that contains that kind of values :

```
[['Electronics', 'Computers & Accessories', 'Laptop & Netbook Computer Accessories', 'Batteries']]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   4638
[['Electronics', 'Computers & Accessories', 'Laptop & Netbook Computer Accessories', 'Chargers & Adapters']]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         3588
[['Electronics', 'Computers & Accessories', 'Laptop & Netbook Computer Accessories', 'Replacement Screens']]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         1654
[['Electronics', 'Computers & Accessories', 'Monitors']]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              723
[['Electronics', 'Camera & Photo', 'Digital Cameras', 'Point & Shoot Digital Cameras']]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               614
[['Electronics', 'Camera & Photo', 'Binoculars & Scopes', 'Binoculars']]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              570
[['Electronics', 'Computers & Accessories', 'Cables & Accessories', 'Memory Cards', 'Micro SD Cards']]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                520
[['Electronics', 'Accessories & Supplies']]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           445
[['Electronics', 'Computers & Accessories', 'Routers']]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               311
[['Electronics', 'Computers & Accessories', 'Networking Products', 'Hubs']]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           289
[['Electronics', 'Computers & Accessories']]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          254
[['Cell Phones & Accessories', 'Cases', 'Basic Cases'], ['Electronics', 'Accessories & Supplies']]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    245
[['Electronics', 'Camera & Photo']]
```

I would like to replace all the occurence of a value from that column, i tried the function replace but i doesnt work

I tried this but it doesnt work

```
df.replace(to_replace=['Cell Phones & Accessories', 'Accessories', 'Headsets', 'Wired Headsets'], value='BONJOUR', inplace=True)
```

can you help me ?

Comment: `df.replace` operates on values which are strings. Your column contains  Lists each with a nested List of several strings. So you need to work through that structure to get at the strings you want to change.

Comment: So i need to change the type of the column ?

Comment: yes they are not included in the column, sorry i didn't see it when i copied the output from google colab, don't pay attention

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to do something like this:-

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Col1':[[['a','b','c']],[['a','b']],[['a','b','d','e']]],
'Col2':[1,2,3]})
print(df)

              Col1   Col2
0      [[a, b, c]]      1
1         [[a, b]]      2
2   [[a, b, d, e]]      3

to_replace=['a','b','e']
value='X'

df['Col1']=df['Col1'].apply(lambda x:[i.replace(i,value) if i in to_replace else i for i in x[0]])

print(df)
            Col1    Col2
0      [X, X, c]      1
1         [X, X]      2
2   [X, X, d, X]      3
```

Comment: i am trying to replace the whole [[a,b,c]] or [[a,b]] and remove the brackets [ ]

Comment: This answer does not take into account the nested List in the penultimate entry of the OP data. Assuming this is intentional which seems probable because of the nesting structure then an extra level of iteration is needed.

Comment: so should i change the type of the column to string and use the replace function ?

Comment: Can you please provide us a snippit of your expected output